# Create matrix of random numbers in C++ without looping

Tags: c++, matrix, boost

I need to create a multidimensional matrix of randomly distributed numbers using a Gaussian distribution, and am trying to keep the program as optimized as possible. Currently I am using Boost matrices, but I can't seem to find anything that accomplishes this without manually looping. Ideally, I would like something similar to Python's numpy.random.randn() function, but this must be done in C++. Is there another way to accomplish this that is faster than manually looping?

Comment: [This sounds like a job for `std::generate`!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) But I'm not sure you'll see much improvement.

Comment: Why do you thing manual loop is slow ?

Comment: I would suggest not worrying about the cost of looping and setting the values of each element of the matrix one by one. I suspect any bottlenecks in your program will lie elsewhere.

Comment: The matrix is part of a convolutional neural network that needs to be able to process large amounts of data, so I am trying to keep it as fast as possible. The matrices could easily have dimensions of +10,000 elements or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to loop anyway, but you can eliminate the array lookup inside your loop. True N-dimensional array indexing is going to be expensive, so you best option is any library (or written yourself) which also provides you with an underlying linear data store.

You can then loop over the entire n-dimensional array as if it was linear, avoiding many multiplications of the indexes by the dimensions.

Another optimization is to do away with the index altogether, and take a pointer to the first element, then iterate the pointer itself, this does away with a whole variable in the CPU which can give the compiler more space for other things. e.g. if you had 1000 elements in a vector:

```
vector<int> data;
data.resize(1000);

int *intPtr = &data[0];
int *endPtr = &data[0] + 1000;

while(intPtr != endPtr)
{
    (*intPtr) == rand_function();
    ++intPtr;
}
```

Here, two tricks have happened. Pre-calculate the end condition outside the loop itself (this avoids a lookup of a function such as vector::size() 1000 times), and working with pointers to the data in memory rather than indexes. An index gets internally converted to a pointer every time it's used to access the array. By storing the "current pointer" and adding 1 to that each time, then the cost of calculating the pointers from indexes 1000 times is eliminated.

This *can* be faster but it depends on the implementation. Compilers can do some of the same hand-optimizations, but not all of them. The rand_function should also be inline to avoid the function call overhead.

A warning however: if you use std::vector with the pointer trick then it's not thread safe, if another thread changed the vector's length during the loop then the vector can get reallocated to a different place in memory. Don't do pointer tricks unless you'd be perfectly comfortable writing your *own* vector, array, table classes as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!